# PHP file deletes MySQL table instead of adding to it

Tags: php, mysql

I recently had my server upgraded to PHP5.4 since PHP5.3 was deprecated. This has caused an issue with my func.php file deleting our mySQL tables instead of adding to them. It used to grab three .txt files (seen below) and insert the data into our mySQL database. I am not sure why this is occuring because the script was working before the update. Any recommendations or advice on fixing this issue would be much appreciated, thank you!

[image]

PHP

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
$argv = $_SERVER['argv'];
$totalArgv = count($argv);
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=******;host=127.0.0.1';
$dsn_training = 'mysql:dbname=******;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = '******';
$password = '*****';
function is_ajax() {
return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
}

function move_files(){
try {
    move_file('sfinder/StoreList.txt');
    move_file('sfinder/StoreProductIndex.txt');
    move_file('sfinder/StoreTypeIndex.txt');
    move_file('training/TrainingCustomerList.txt');
}
catch(Exception $e){
    die_with_error($e->getMessage());
}

//sleep(1);
//Return JSON
$return["json"] = json_encode($return);
//echo json_encode($return);
}

function empty_table($dbconnection, $tablename){
try{
    $sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE " . $tablename;
    $sth = $dbconnection->prepare($sql);
    //$sth->bindParam(':tablename', $tablename, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    // The row is actually inserted here
    $sth->execute();
    //echo " [+]Table '" . $tablename . "' has been emptied.<br>";
    $sth->closeCursor();
}
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    die_with_error($e->getMessage()); 
}
}

function copy_additional($dbconn, $tablename){
try{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO stores
        (csid, store_name, address1, address2, city, state, zip, phone, fax, website, coord_lat, coord_long, x_axis, y_axis, z_axis)
        SELECT csid, store_name, address1, address2, city, state, zip, phone, fax, website, coord_lat, coord_long, x_axis, y_axis, z_axis
        FROM " . $tablename . ";";
    $sth = $dbconn->prepare($sql);

    // Execute SQL command
    $sth->execute();
    //echo " [+]CSV File for '" . $tablename . "' Table Imported.<br>";
    $sth->closeCursor();
}
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    die_with_error($e->getMessage()); 
}
```

Comment: well, for one thing, you're using two different variables for your queries `$dbconnection` and `$dbconn` so it's really hard to know which is which. Plus, none of those are defined anywhere.  So there you are; a few things you can think about. `$dsn_training` that's a stray variable, btw.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I don't see why they would need `VALUES`; they are using the `INSERT SELECT` form of `INSERT`... unless you are talking about code outside of MySQL of course.

Comment: @Uueerdo I stand corrected; ok. However, the rest of my comment applies, which I will edit the part about values. Edit: edited.

Comment: too many unknowns here.

Comment: i see. i left a few functions out of the code that seemed unnecessary, i will re-check the code. thanks :)